# Fatal error when trying to start a transaction in PHP 7.3 with mysqli

Tags: php, sql, mysqli, transactions

I want to execute the following transaction:

```
START TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO
   `orders` (producten, totaalprijs, account_id) 
VALUES
   (
      "{\"601bced33b191\":{\"naam\":\"Sierkussens binnen\", \"alias\":\"sierkussens - binnen\", \"url\":\"https:\\ / \\ / printzelf.nl\\ / new\\ / product\\ / sierkussens - binnen ? term = sierkussen\", \"afbeelding\":\"cms\\ / images\\ / producten\\ / textiel_producten\\ / Sierkussens\\ / sierkussen_1.jpg\", \"aantal\":\"1\", \"hoogte\":null, \"breedte\":null, \"uploaden\":\"1\", \"specificaties\":{\"Formaat\":{\"waarde\":\"40 x 40 cm\"}, \"Materiaal\":{\"waarde\":\"Dekostof\"}, \"Samenstelling\":{\"waarde\":\"Hoes\"}, \"Kleur garen\":{\"waarde\":\"Zwart\"}, \"Kleur rits\":{\"waarde\":\"Zwart\"}, \"Ontwerp\":{\"waarde\":\"PRO ontwerpcontrole\"}}, \"prijs\":\"13.99\", \"totaalprijs\":13.99, \"canvas\":\"{\\n \\\"customer_id\\\": \\\"33\\\", \\n \\\"order_id\\\": \\\"123\\\", \\n \\\"quantity\\\": \\\"1\\\", \\n \\\"rulers\\\": null, \\n \\\"canvas_size\\\": \\\"0x0\\\", \\n \\\"bleed\\\": null, \\n \\\"safety_margin\\\": null, \\n \\\"dpi\\\": null, \\n \\\"multiple_layouts\\\": null, \\n \\\"procheck\\\": \\\"y\\\", \\n \\\"multiple_pages\\\": \\\"1\\\", \\n \\\"product_name\\\": \\\"Sierkussens binnen\\\", \\n \\\"thumbnail\\\": \\\"cms\\\\\\ / images\\\\\\ / producten\\\\\\ / textiel_producten\\\\\\ / Sierkussens\\\\\\ / sierkussen_1.jpg\\\"\\n}\"}}", "19", "33" 
   )
;
UPDATE
   `orders` 
SET
   order_id = CONCAT(account_id, ".", id) 
WHERE
   id = LAST_INSERT_ID();
COMMIT;
```

So I tried starting a transaction like this:

```
$conn->autocommit(FALSE);
$conn->query('
INSERT INTO orders
(
    producten,
    totaalprijs,
    account_id
)
VALUES
(
    "'.$conn->real_escape_string($encodedproductenarray).'",
    "'.$conn->real_escape_string(subtractbtw($subtotaalcheckoutafr)).'",
    "'.$conn->real_escape_string($_SESSION['user']['id']).'"
)');
$conn->query('
UPDATE orders SET order_id = CONCAT(account_id, ".", id)
WHERE id = LAST_INSERT_ID()');
$conn->commit();
```

But this gives me the following error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Connection::autocommit()
```

Am I doing something wrong?

$conn is my connection class that contains the following:

```
session_start();
class Connection {
    // Configure Database Vars
    private $host     = 'localhost';
    private $username = 'sdgsdg';
    private $password = 'sdgsdg!';
    private $db_name  = 'dsgsd';
    public $db;

    function __construct() {
        // Create connection
        $db = new mysqli($this->host, $this->username, $this->password, $this->db_name);
        // Check connection
        if ($db->connect_errno > 0) {
            die('Unable to connect to the database: '.$db->connect_error);
        }
        $this->db = $db;
    }

    public function query($query) {
        $db = $this->db;
        $this->db->query('SET NAMES utf8');
        if (!$result = $this->db->query($query)) {
            die('There was an error running the query ['.$db->error.']');
        } else {
            return $result;
        }
    }

    public function multi_query($query) {
        $db = $this->db;
        if (!$result = $this->db->multi_query($query)) {
            die('There was an error running the multi query ['.$db->error.']');
        } else {
            return $result;
        }
    }

    public function real_escape_string($value) {
        return $this->db->real_escape_string($value);
    }

    public function inserted_id() {
        return $this->db->insert_id;
    }
}

$conn = new Connection();
```

I've also tried adding the entire transaction inside a query like this:

```
$insertorder = '
START TRANSACTION;
    INSERT INTO orders
    (
        producten,
        totaalprijs,
        account_id
    )
    VALUES
    (
        "'.$conn->real_escape_string($encodedproductenarray).'",
        "'.$conn->real_escape_string(subtractbtw($subtotaalcheckoutafr)).'",
        "'.$conn->real_escape_string($_SESSION['user']['id']).'"
    );
    UPDATE orders SET order_id = CONCAT(account_id, ".", id)
    WHERE id = LAST_INSERT_ID();
COMMIT;';
$insertordercon = $conn->query($insertorder);
```

But this gives me a syntax error.

Comment: If you're using your custom connection class, of course you can't just call `mysqli`'s method on it. You would need to implement a method that tells it to call `autocommit` on `$this->db`.

Comment: `$conn->db->autocommit();` Remember the function is on the mysqli object, not your wrapper class. Or you need to create an equivalent function in your class which calls the mysqli method (although, that's relatively pointless really)

Comment: You should also read up on using [prepared statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) with placeholders instead of manually escaping the values and putting them directly into the query like that.

Comment: You're also trying to execute a string containing multiple queries with your `query()`-method instead of the `multi_query()`-method.

Comment: @ADyson Thank you I got it working that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a `mysqli` object in your class. That has all the methods you are looking to use. Do something like this:

```php
$conn->db->autocommit(FALSE);
$conn->query('
INSERT INTO orders
(
    producten,
    totaalprijs,
    account_id
)
VALUES
(
    "'.$conn->real_escape_string($encodedproductenarray).'",
    "'.$conn->real_escape_string(subtractbtw($subtotaalcheckoutafr)).'",
    "'.$conn->real_escape_string($_SESSION['user']['id']).'"
)');
$conn->query('
UPDATE orders SET order_id = CONCAT(account_id, ".", id)
WHERE id = LAST_INSERT_ID()');
$conn->db->commit();
```

Alternatively, you could implement these methods in your class. You have already done so for `query` and `real_escape_string`, so it should be easy. Just insert into the class:

```php
public function autocommit($b) {
    $this->db->autocommit($b);
}

public function commit() {
   $this->db->commit();
}
```

...or similar.